# Difference in pronunciation between "your" and "you're"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronouns, possessives, contractions

I'm a native English speaker (Texas counts, I suppose), and I pronounce "your" to rhyme with "core", and "you're" to rhyme with "cure". Is it just me or did I pick this up somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, we ain't fixin' to discriminate aginst y'all ;)

Comment: Interesting.  I regularly have trouble writing there/their/they're, since I pronounce them the same, but I pronounce your/you're slightly differently and rarely type one when I mean the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The American English pronunciation for *you're* is /jʊ(ə)r/, /jər/; the pronunciation for *your* is /jʊ(ə)r/, /jər/.
In British English, the pronunciation are respectively /jɔː/, /jə/, /jʊə/; and /jɔː/, /jʊə/.

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with /jɔːr/.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: This is correct, but many/most British English speakers frequently use say /jɔː/ for both *you're* and *your*.

Comment: @psmears: There is also who pronounces _you're_ as /jə/. I don't know how much people use that pronunciation, but it still one of the possible pronunciations in British English.

Comment: This is probably a helpful answer to people who know what "/jʊ(ə)r/" means, but from the context of the question, it should be clear that I'm not one of them.

Comment: It means the pronunciation could be /jʊr/ or /jʊər/. /ər/ is the pronunciation for _r_.

Comment: Not all dictionaries are the same; my hard-copy *American Heritage dictionary* says *your* can rhyme with *core*, while *you're* can't. The online *Mirriam-Webster* says you can rhyme both of these with *core*. See my answer below.

Comment: I reported the pronunciation I found in the NOAD and the OED; both the dictionaries use IPA.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: The NOAD and the OED are both compiled on the wrong side of the pond. And in this case, they get it wrong. I'm sure there are American dialects that pronounce your and yours with /jɔɹ/.

Comment: @Peter Shor: There are also some dialects spoken in the United Kingdom that are rhotic. The NOAD is compiled by American editors.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes, I wasn't disagreeing with the /jə/ pronunciation - that's very common too, especially when the word is unstressed. I was just adding another common pronunciation to the ones mentioned in the dictionary :)

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't have said the NOAD and OED got it wrong. They do give the standard American pronunciations, but they don't seem to be making a comprehensive survey of all the dialectical pronunciations. It's quite possible the OP's pronunciations are common in his part of Texas.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: The *American Heritage Dictionary* agrees with you. They list /yôr/ as an acceptable variant pronunciation for *your* but not for *you're*. However, since they don't say what dialects this pronunciation is found in, I don't know whether the speculation in my original post below is correct.

ORIGINAL POST: In the U.S., there are a number of accents which don't have the phoneme /ʊɹ/ in *moor*. (My mother, from rural Illinois, had one of these accents, and I used this accent's pronunciation for many of these words when I was young.) In these accents, the phoneme is replaced by either /ɝ/ as in *purr* or /ɔɹ/ as in *pore*; the rule is that generally, words that are pronounced with /jʊɹ/ (pure, cure) the phoneme is replaced by /jɝ/, and words that are pronounced with no /j/ (*poor*, *moor*, *sure*), the phoneme is replaced by /ɔɹ/.<sup>1</sup> It may be that in some of these accents, *you're* and *your* get disambiguated by having *you're* rhyme with *purr*, and *your* rhyme with *pore*. I do know that pronouncing *you're* with /ɔɹ/ sounds wrong to me, whereas pronouncing *your* either way sounds fine.

I'm just guessing, but it's possible that one of these accents influenced your pronunciation of *your* and *you're*.

<sup>1</sup> This rule only works for the final syllable of words. Otherwise, the sound generally changes to /ɝ/.

Comment: /jɔɹ/ ≠ /jʊɹ/ ≠ /jɚ/

Comment: @tchrist: I agree; I pronounce more, moor, and myrrh all differently, but not all Americans do. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 4):

I looked up the dictionary, since I'm not a native speaker and the **IPA** gives the same pronunciation, even though there are two possible pronunciations.

> **your** |yôr; yoŏr| - 
>   possessive adjective 
>   **1.** belonging to or associated with the person or people that the speaker is addressing : *what is your name?*

and

> **you're** |yoŏr; yôr| - 
>   contraction of
>   you are : you're an angel, Deb!

So I suppose that what you referred to was about the **accent**? Considering you said you are from Texas and not, for example, from England or another English speaking country.

Answer (score 4):

In the U.K. we are taught that they all sound the same (at least I was).  Its this that gives the words their difficulty for native speakers.  When you learn to write you realize that one spoken word is written in different ways that depends upon the context.

It could be that in some schools they give slightly different pronunciations to the words, so that when children learn to speak they realize that they are different words from an earlier age - ready for when they learn to write.

A German speaking friend remarked once that he found the mistake very funny. But he learnt to write English at the same time as he learnt to speak, so they were always different words.  There was never the confusion.

Its similar to their, there and they're - for me they are all said the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is intriguing.

In theory, they should sound the same; though one person might pronounce the words differently from another person, they should only have one pronunciation for both words.

That said, I am a from England and there are indeed many pronunciation variations without even travelling to the other Eng speaking countries (America, Canada, Australia - even India and Singapore).

What makes this even more difficult to comment on is that I don't know how you pronounce the words 'core' and 'cure' as there are places in England where these words would 'rhyme' with each other - of course 'cure' has a diphthong (the inclusion of the 'y' sound at the beginning of the vowel sound) but they could both end with the same sound (like the word 'or').

c - or

c - y - or

So...

Your - you're

There is no real reason that one person should pronounce these two words differently; they are homophones, which means they sound identical.

However, dialectical variations are innumerable and so we can't really tell you you are wrong.

Comment: Hi, @tchrist. Unless I'm missing something, the words 'your' and 'you're' are not available on that page. Perhaps a direct link to those examples? But, to clarify, I accept that in different dialects there would be differences. My point is that in standard pronunciation, those words (your and you're) are homonyms. Other homonyms include (there - their - they're) (lye - lie). Of course, as you travel between areas with different dialects, you may well find the words within these groups to have distinct pronunciations but there is no denying that it is a dialectic effect, I'm sure you'll agree.

Comment: @Karl: In what "theory" should these two words sound the same?

Comment: Based on RP as the accepted standard for English pronunciation. As stated, I accept that different dialects would have their own variations, but as an answer to the question posed, these two words are homonyms in standard English pronunciation. I'm surprised that that fact is being questioned.

Comment: Also, OED online gives the following as the same IPA for both 'your' and 'you're': **/jɔː/, /jʊə/** with 'you're' having the added possibility of **/jə/**, such as a some Northern English dialects might have in an utterance like "you're kidding, aren't you?"

Comment: Funny, I don't pronounce they're, their, and there the same either.

Comment: As I said in all of my comments, I am talking about standard pronunciation. RP has no 'r' here as it is non-rhotic. Once more for clarity - In standard pronunciation, these words are homonyms. With regional dialects, they may be different. RP is accepted as standard pronunciation. That doesn't mean to say that everyone uses it, even I don't. However, the IPA system was in fact written **based on** the RP dialect. Hence, when discussing standard pronunciation, it is normal to refer to RP.

Comment: You will see that @Kiamlaluno and @Alenanno's answers both support mine in that the words are homonyms - thought they might be pronounced differently in different regions, they remain homonyms. I would like to point out, as I haven't thus far, that I am English, and so use BrEng, the *standard* for which is RP. I understand that RP would not have much presence in America, but it still is considered *standard* in terms of pronunciation.

Comment: Americans don't rhyme *core* and *cure*. At least, not in any dialects I am familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to pronounce your/you're differently. I pronounce "your" as [jɔ˞] or [jɻ̩] and "you're" as [ju.ɻ̩] or [jʊ˞]. However in fast speech, you're can become [jɻ̩] as well. I typically say you're as 2 syllables, because I almost always pronounce "'re" as /ɻ̩/ except in fast speech. Similarly, I differentiate between there/their/they're. "There" becomes [ðɛ˞], "their" [ðeɻ], and "they're" [ðe.ɻ̩]. However the distinction is lost in fast speech when they all become [ðɛ˞].

Answer (score -3):

*Your*: [ye-or].

*You’re*: [you-r].

*You’re* is a contraction of *you* and *are*. We remove/clip the ‘ay’ sound leaving ‘re’ ([r] for ‘Rudolph’, **not** [ar] for ‘arse’), and then we run the two words together forming [you-r].

To pronounce *your* and *you’re* the same creates confusion, and personally I think it is incorrect: they are not homophones.

Comment: It’s not a matter of “correctness”. It is simply what people do.

Comment: @tchrist, I wish my professors would follow that mantra when grading my papers. They continuously mistake “simply what I do” for some sort of errors.

Comment: @theUg Clearly you must be referring to *oral* papers, since we are treating with pronunciation of homophones here.

Comment: I just checked five online dictionaries, and they all disagreed with this answer (that is, they all listed **identical** pronunciations for both words). NOTE: They also listed more than one pronunciation for each word, so it's quite possible for someone to pronounce each of these two words uniquely. That said, the assertion that "they are not homophones" is fallacious.